# OpenGL Hide part of the world

Tags: c++, opengl

I actually use openGL 1.20 and I need to hide part of the world. For example I would like that everything higher than 100 in my z-axis (or any other axis) should not be displayed. 
I tried something with `glClipPlane` and `glScissor` but it seems that it only concerns the view from the camera. 
The goal is to see the inside of objects.
What should I use ?

Edit : 
I tried this with `glClipPlane` but I think that my equation is false :

```
    static const GLdouble equation[] = {0,0,1000,1 };

    glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);

    glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, equation);
```

Comment: then set the value of far clipping plane of your frustum

Comment: It's not what I want, I want to hide from an axis of the opengl World

Answer (score 0):

if you have low horsepower graphics card use mesa.it runs opengl/glsl 3.3 .
then learn glsl and there you can just gain position of a fragment in fragment shader.Deploy `if` conditions, `gl_FragColor=..` and add

```
else discard;
```

Thats all.